# How can I make an iFrame fullscreen on a button click, without JS?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, fullscreen

wI'm currently trying to fullscreen an iFrame on a button click, similar to [this website](https://poki.com/en/g/stickman-hook). This website has a bar that goes fullscreen with the iframed game, which is what I would ideally like to do. I can't really figure out how to do this. If possible, I would prefer to use no JavaScript, but let me know if there is an easier method with JavaScript. I'm pretty new to coding, so any help would mean a lot.

Below is the iFrame code and the image/title of the game.

````
  <html>
    <iframe src="https://1v1.lol" style="border:0px #ffffff none;" name="" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="465px" width="740px" allowfullscreen="yes" ></iframe>
    <p>
<span style="color: #000000;">
<img src="https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/image.webp" style="width: 35px; position: relative; left: 15px">
<span>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp1v1.lol</span>
</span> 
    </p>
</html>```
````

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "fullscreen", do you mean iframe takes the whole page, this can be done with CSS or fullscreen using the computer's F11?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "fullscreen". If you want your [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) element to take the whole page, then use CSS to do such a thing.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

iframe {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://example.com"></iframe>
```

Of course, to toggle such a thing, you need to use JavaScript.

```js
let iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
let toggleButton = document.getElementById("toggleButton");

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    iframe.style.width = iframe.style.width === "100vw" ? "50vw" : "100vw";
    iframe.style.height = iframe.style.height === "100vh" ? "50vh" : "100vh";
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#iframe {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#toggleButton {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: cursive;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://example.com"></iframe>
<div id="toggleButton">Toggle</div>
```

If you want your element to take the computer's whole screen, use the [`requestFullscreen()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen) method.

```js
let iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
let toggleButton = document.getElementById("toggleButton");

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
iframe.requestFullscreen();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#iframe {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#toggleButton {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: cursive;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://example.com"></iframe>
<div id="toggleButton">Toggle</div>
```

***Note:** It may not work in the [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/22152755), but it'll work locally.*

Answer (score -1):

The fullscreen functionality is directly dependent on browser API and you have to use a Fullscreen API for this using some JS code. Here is an example of this:-

```
<iframe id="iframeID" src="some-url"></iframe>
<button id="toggleFull">Toggle Fullscreen</button>
```

Now we use a little bit of JavaScript to toggle an iframe to fullscreen.

```
const togglebtn = document.getElementById("toggleFull");
const iframe = document.getElementById("iframeID");
```

Then apply click handler event to the button with following conditions as:-

```
 togglebtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
     if(iframe.requestFullscreen){
          iframe.requestFullscreen();
     }else if(iframe.mozRequestFullScreen){ // Firefox
          iframe.mozRequestFullScreen();
     }else if(iframe.webkitRequestFullscreen){ // Chrome,Safari,Opera
          iframe.webkitRequestFullscreen();
     }else if(iframe.msRequestFullscreen){ // I.E, Edge
          iframe.msRequestFullscreen();
     }
   });
```

NOTE:- Fullscreen API will trigger respective browser-specific methods to request a fullscreen for an iframe.

Comment: Why are you testing for the **experimental** implementations of `requestFullScreen` in three different browser engines? It's 2023. The API is stable!

Comment: I know @Quentin, I was just explaining with more details because as he told he is pretty new to coding that's why he has to know browser compatibility methods for fullscreen. Everything is improving day by day but it doesn't mean we forget about the core or initial build of an application.

Comment: Why does he need to know about compatibility methods to make it work with browsers that have been obsolete for half a decade?

Comment: Bro, it's just an example and how he will use this method is totally dependent on him. And you are talking like a newbie programmer who only wants to focus on improvements but not focus on deprecated things or knowledge. Something is not useful that doesn't mean it's useless. So everyone has their own perspective specially as a developer.

Comment: "And you are talking like a newbie programmer who only wants to focus on improvements but not focus on deprecated things or knowledge" — Teaching stuff that was relevant  half a decade ago can, occasionally, be useful but if you're going to do that then its important to *actually teach that* and not present it as copy-pasta code that is best practice in 2023.

Comment: Anyway, I guess what @Quentin means is that if something isn't needed or not useful or deprecated, it shouldn't be taught. The web evolved, evolves, and will evolve. We should focus on new stuff, not things that were made from a decade. Like `<center>` tag is deprecated, it shouldn't be used anymore, nor taught anywhere but rather we should focus on new stuff like `text-align: center;`.

Comment: @LightningMcQueen Learning new things and taking knowledge there is a big gap between them. And I was not answered wrong but just tried to explain better.  #Quentin - "Be useful but if you're going to do that then it's important to actually teach that" So teaching is not about just learning new things but you have to know the past or history. Like in reactjs we only focus on how to make an extensive UI but not focus on the reconciliation algorithm, so if we see clearly then the virtualDOM algorithm is not useful in our daily web routine but you also know how much it is important to us.